# The input field is not centered when the keyboard appears

Tags: java, android, android-layout

The effect of centering the focus on the input field disappears when the keyboard appears,
and the keyboard closes the input field and the text entered by the
user is not visible.
Please help to solve this problem.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
            android:name=".BrowserActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Game"
            android:exported="true"
            android:resizeableActivity="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            android:screenOrientation="sensor">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <data android:scheme="http" />
                <data android:scheme="https" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

themes.xml

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.Game" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed" tools:targetApi="q">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode">
            shortEdges
        </item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="21">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

    <style name="AlertDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.Dialog.Alert">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorText</item>
        <item name="buttonBarButtonStyle">@style/AlertDialogButtonTheme</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AlertDialogButtonTheme" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.ButtonBar.AlertDialog">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorFg</item>
    </style>

    <style name="EditTextTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorText</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorFg</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="editTextColor">@color/colorText</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHighlight">@color/colorTextHighlight</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

activity_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".BrowserActivity">
        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

BrowserActivity

```
public class BrowserActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView webView;
    public WebSettings webSettings;
    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private static final int LONG_SWIPE_DISTANCE = 1000;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);

        webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, new CustomGestureListener());
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Update...");
        setupWebView();
    }

    private void setupWebView() {
        webView.setWebViewClient(new GameWebViewClient(this));

        webView.setWebChromeClient(new GameWebChromeClient(this));

        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);

        webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webSettings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);

        CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
        cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            cookieManager.setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(webView,true);
        }

        String ua = webSettings.getUserAgentString()
                .replace("; wv", "");

        int uaIndex = ua.indexOf("Version");

        ua = ua.substring(0, uaIndex)
                .concat(getString(R.string.app_name))
                .concat(ua.substring(uaIndex));

        webSettings.setUserAgentString(ua);

        webView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
            }
        });

        webView.loadUrl("");
    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        if (hasFocus) {
            View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
            int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;
            decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }


    private class CustomGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
            final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;
            float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
            float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
            if (Math.abs(diffY) > Math.abs(diffX) && diffY > LONG_SWIPE_DISTANCE && webView.getScrollY() == 0) {
                refreshWebView();
                return true;
            }

            if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY) && Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                if (diffX > 0) {
                    if (webView.canGoBack()) {
                        webView.goBack();
                    }
                } else {
                    if (webView.canGoForward()) {
                        webView.goForward();
                    }
                }

                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    private void refreshWebView() {
        progressDialog.show();

        webView.reload();

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(@NonNull Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {}
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putString("webViewUrl", webView.getUrl());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        String savedUrl = savedInstanceState.getString("webViewUrl");
        if (savedUrl != null) {
            webView.loadUrl(savedUrl);
        }
    }
}
```

When removing from the code:

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

...........................................

```
@Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        if (hasFocus) {
            View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
            int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;
            decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
        }
    }
```

Everything works.
The app must be completely full screen. That is, the toolbar and the bottom part with buttons should be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

When I remove from the code:

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

Everything works, but requires full screen mode.